# Get last four character after removing the space in php

Tags: php

I have a string `4345 5666 7768 6555` I first want to remove its spaces after I want to get last four characters, how it is possible using PHP?

Comment: `$result = substr(str_replace(' ','',$string),-4);`
http://php.net/substr http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$str = "4345 5666 7768 6555";

$str = str_replace(" ","",$str);
echo $str = substr($str,-4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str); // replace spaces
echo substr($str, -4); // get last four characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "4345 5666 7768 6555";

$str = str_replace(" ","",$str);
echo $str =trim(substr($str,-4));
```